# How can I store address of dynamically created objects in C++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, virtual-functions

```cpp
class A 
{
public:
    virtual void show()
    {
        cout << "you are in A";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "you are in B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a[5];
    A **aa[5];
    B *b[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new A;
        aa[i] = &a[i];
        aa[i]->show();
        b[i] = new B;
        aa[i] = &b[i];
        aa[i]->show();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> **error** : request for member 'show' in *aa[i] which of type pointer 'A*'

> **error** : invalid conversion from 'B**'  to 'A**' [-fpermisive]

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: Consider making a [mcve] instead of comments like `//INSIDE MAIN`. Help us help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it, like showing us a complete copy-paste of the errors yoy get. And actually asking a question.

Comment: error : request for member 'show' in *aa[i] which of type pointer 'A * '

Comment: error : invalid conversion from 'B**' to ' A **' [-fpermisive]

Comment: Where there is `new` operator, there must be `delete` operator

Comment: not yet working.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have `A **aa[5]`, it is an array of pointers to pointers, so you need triple indirection to call the `show` method

```
(*aa[i])->show();
```

You also can't store `B**` in it, as you can only (implicitly) convert to a base class with a single level of indirection.

However, it is not at all clear what you are trying to do.  More commonly you would just use an array of pointers and only need double indirection:

```
A *a[5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (i & 1)
        a[i] = new A;
    else
        a[i] = new B;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    a[i]->show();
```

double pointers are rarely needed, so why are you using them?

Comment: thanks for your help, but my second error still exist                                                      
error : invalid conversion from 'B**' to 'A**' [-fpermisive]

Comment: Right, because you can't convert to the base class with more than one indirection -- it makes no sense to do so (and is unsafe, in general), so the compiler doesn't let you do it.

Comment: i am using virtual function, so how can i call show () of B class from pointer of base class A in case of dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: @AnmolSingh: that's the way virtual functions work -- they call based on the dynamic (actual) type of the object, not the type of the pointer.